# How to create a simple encryption endpoint in node such that only the encrypted text can be returned back for future decryption?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I need to implement an api endpoint that just takes a `id` in query param, then sends its encrypted value back. For that I was looking into the `crypto` module in node, and I found it a bit complex. One thing that I donot get is how am I suppose to use the `iv`? I plan to store the encryption `key` in the `env` such that every `id` can be decrypted using that same `key`. So, should I also store the `iv` in the env? Is that a good practice?

I have seen some apis actually randomly generates `iv` for each request, and return it alongside the encrypted text, such that the user can send them both later for decryption. But for my usecase, I cannot send two separate data back to the user. I can concat `iv` in the encrypted text, but for some values, the encrypted text in itself is too long for my use case. Any suggestion on what might be the best approach for my case?

Comment: The text being too long really ought to be a separate question, but you could consider using Node's [Zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) (not to be confused with *nix zlib library). I'd recommend `BrotliCompress` and `BrotliDecompress` to get maximum compression, but `Gzip` will be faster compressing. Be sure to compress before encrypting and vice-versa decrypting.

Comment: *...but for some values, the encrypted text in itself is too long for my use case...* How long is 'too long'? How long is the id? Why encrypt the id at all?

Answer (score 1):

Initialisation vectors are important to prevent attackers using brute force methods to decrypt data *after* a breach has occurred, i.e. in the event the DB has been copied/stolen.

In summary, if you encrypted the same password twice, with the same key, but without an IV, you will get the same encrypted string output. By adding an IV you will get a different output with the same password, but you have to store the IV along with the encrypted data, see [Cipher Block Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). This makes it much harder to decrypt breached password databases as the attacker cannot use dictionaries of common passwords to test keys for a match within the data. In relational databases an IV is typically called a 'salt', in Postgres for example, you should generate a new salt when storing each password, like so:

```sql
UPDATE user SET password = crypt('new password', gen_salt('md5'));
```

For your use case I'm not certain if you need an IV, it depends on how the encrypted data is supposed to be used and/or stored. If you decide you don't need one, you can just omit it either of these ways:

##### 1: Pass `null` instead of an IV:

```js
const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-192-ccm', key, null);
```

##### 2: (Deprecated since Node 10) Use the `createCipher` function:

```js
const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-192-ccm', key);
```